# Controller/Services.js not working with href to go to template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an app to display a list of store locations and I have a list of ionic items that I can display. However, I cannot seem to select them and have them link to another view that has details about the selected item.

This is the view that contains the link:

```
<ion-content has-footer="true" has-header="true">

    <ion-list has-footer="true" has-header="true" can-swipe="listCanSwipe">

        <ion-item  detail-push ng-repeat="locale in locations" type="item-text-wrap" onclick = "#/tab/location/{{locale.friendlyName}}">                   
            <h2><b> {{locale.friendlyName}}</b></h2>
            <h3>                   
                {{locale.address}}, {{locale.city}}, {{locale.state}}
            </h3>    
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar position="bottom" class="bar-balanced">
        <a class = "button icon ion-earth item-center" href="#/tab/map" onclick="mapOn()">Locations Near Me</a> 
    </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the state:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
    // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
    $stateProvider

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
      .state('tab', {
          url: '/tab',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      })

    // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

    .state('tab.dash', {
        url: '/dash',
        views: {
            'tab-dash': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
                controller: 'DashCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.location', {
        url: '/location',
        views: {
            'tab-location': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-location.html',
                controller: 'LocCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.account', {
        url: '/account',
        views: {
            'tab-account': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
                controller: 'AccountCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('tab.map', {
        url: '/map',
        views: {
            'tab-location': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-map.html',
                controller: 'MapCtrl'
            }
        }
    }
    )
    .state('tab.detail', {
        url: '/location/:locId',
        views: {
            'tab-location': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/location-detail.html',
                controller: 'DetCtrl'
            }
        }
    });
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/location');

})
.directive('hideTabs', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.$watch(attributes.hideTabs, function (value) {
                $rootScope.hideTabs = value;
            });

            scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function () {
                $rootScope.hideTabs = false;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and here is the controller:

```
.controller('DetCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, Locations) {
Locations.get($stateParams.locId).then(function (result) {
    $scope.loc = result;
})
});
```

I assume there is some disconnect with the state params but I have checked and rechecked values. I am relatively new to angular and Ionic platform so I am worried I may just be missing some intricacy of the platform I just have not learned yet. 
I can provide a screen shot if that helps but basically the list is displayed and scroll-able but nothing can be selected.

Here is the services.js

```
    angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Locations', function ($http, $q) {
    // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
    var url = "https://portal.mobilequbes.com/api/kiosks?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    return {
        all: function () {
            return $http.jsonp(url)
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result.data;
                });
        },
        remove:{
        },
        get: function (locId) {
            for (i = 0; i < Locations.all().length; i++) {
                if (Locations.all()[i].friendlyName == locId) {
                    return Locations.all()[i];
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return null;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ion-item, instead of this:

```
onclick = "#/tab/location/{{locale.friendlyName}}"
```

you want something like this:

```
ui-sref='tab.detail({locId : locale.friendlyName})'
```

If you're trying to handle click events in angular, you need to use the [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick#!) directive. However, ui-router will handle this for you by using ui-sref.

Comment: I tried that and I tried using href or ng-click but the items are still unresponsive. They do not even register any click taking place.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console? Does the map link work?

Comment: Map link works fine, its not access to the data that is the problem. I think it is either some syntatical thing I am unfamiliar with or I am missing some concept with how controllers and view work in this way

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the footer-bar wrapped in an ion-content section, but you shouldn't need that. Can you also post all your $stateProvider code?

Comment: I posted the complete app.js